# lexical_cast strtof strtold lose accuracy?

Tags: c++, lexical-cast

Here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main(void) {
    const char * str = "277499.84";

    std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<double>(str) << std::endl;
    std::cout << strtof(str, NULL) << std::endl;
    std::cout << strtold(str, NULL) << std::endl;
    std::cout << atof(str) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
277500
277500
277500
277500
```

Why the output are not 277499.84?

Comment: The default precision is 6 I suppose, just like for `printf`'s `%f`. Change it if you don't like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the operations themselves losing accuracy, but the *output*.

You can use the I/O manipulator [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) to control the numeric precision.  The following will use the full precision of a double (assuming the stream is set for decimal output).

```
double value = boost::lexical_cast<double>(str);
std::cout << std::setprecision( std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1 ) << value;
```

Or you can use [`std::ios_base::precision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision).  This is useful if you want to restore the precision to the original value after.

```
auto old_precision = cout.precision( std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1 );
cout << value;
cout.precision( old_precision );
```